# Why is an $n$th power a norm in a Kummer extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field containing the $n$th roots of unity.  Then by Kummer theory, $[F^{\ast} : F^{\ast n}]$ (which is finite) is equal to the cardinality of $\textrm{Gal}(E/F)$, where $E$ is $F$ adjoined with all the $n$th roots of unity in $F$.

Also $F^{\ast}/N_{E/F}(E^{\ast})$ has cardinality $|\textrm{Gal}(E/F)|$ by local class field theory.  This would give us $N_{E/F}(E^{\ast}) = F^{\ast n}$ provided we could show just one inclusion.  Why is it that every element of $F^{\ast n}$ is a norm?